# How to do a SQL GROUP BY on multiple dimensions in Tableau?

Tags: sql, group-by, tableau-desktop

I am able to do SQL `GROUP BY x` in Tableau by right clicking the dimension `x` and then clicking `Create Group`. How do I do `GROUP BY x, y` where `x` and `y` are two separate dimensions or columns?

Comment: Tableau does the aggregation by default. Whenever you pull two dimension x and y  and a metric to a tableau view it will aggregate the metric to those two dimension...
Tableau group is something different, which we use to categorize the values of a dimension. For eg: if we have a product field with n number of product names we can use tableau group to categorize the product names to some product categories.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply drag and drop `x` and `y` pills in the column/row area and then drag and drop your measure in the marks area. In this way, your measure(s) will be grouped by `x` and `y`.
If you click on the measure in the marks area you can select the aggregation function.

Look at this: [Data Aggregation in Tableau](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-gb/calculations_aggregation.htm)